# Quicktime: set 'elng' atom, or AVAssetTrack's extendedLanguageTag property

Tags: macos, quicktime, macos-carbon, qtkit

I have some videos for which I need to set an extended language tag for each of the tracks. I haven't found any app that does this, so I'm trying to do it in code.

The documentation for the `elng` tag is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap2/qtff2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH204-SW16).

The place I'm trying to read that tag is on iOS, where `extendedLanguageTag` is a read-only property of AVAssetTrack. Essentially I want to set something on the track in my QuickTime file that can be retrieved using that property.

I don't care which QuickTime API I use — in this attempt, I'm using QTKit to open the video and then using the old C QuickTime API to try and set the tag. However, it isn't working. (No error codes are being returned, the tag just isn't being set.)

```
NSError *error = nil;
QTMovie *mov = [QTMovie movieWithFile:filename error:&error];
NSArray *tracks = mov.tracks;

int i=0;
for (QTTrack *track in tracks)
{
    OSErr err;

    Track qtrack = track.quickTimeTrack;

    Media media = GetTrackMedia(qtrack);

    QTAtomContainer props;
    err = GetMediaPropertyAtom(media, &props);

    if (props == NULL)
    {
        err = QTNewAtomContainer(&props);
    }

    char nt[5]=   "en-gb" ;

    QTAtom newAtom;
    err = QTInsertChild(props, kParentAtomIsContainer, 'elng', 1, 0, 5,  &nt, &newAtom);

    if (newAtom == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"Insert child failed");
    }

    SetMediaPropertyAtom(media, props);
}

[mov writeToFile:@"/Users/amy/Downloads/testfilmAgain43.mov" withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieFlatten]];
```

I haven't actually ever used the QuickTime C API before, so I may be completely misunderstanding something. Can anyone help?